# JSON in PHP not correctly formatted from an JQuery Ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a JQuery AJAX request send off some JSON data to a PHP script, however, when it comes to manipulating the data or even trying to access it, it behaves like a string but I need it to behave like an associative array.

**JavaScript**

```
var all_data = [];

$.each($("[id*=card]"), function(i, value) {
  var name_a = $(value).find('#story_name_div').text();
  var text_a = $(value).find('#story_text_div').text();
  var point_a = $(value).find('#story_point_div').text();
  var phase_a = $(value).find('#story_phase').val();
  var date_a = $(value).find('#story_date').val();
  var author_a = $(value).find('#username_div').text();

var story_data = {
  "name": name_a ,
  "text": text_a ,
  "point": point_a ,
  "data": phase_a ,
  "date": date_a ,
  "author": author_a 
};

all_data.push(story_data);

});

$.ajax({
   url: 'save_server_script.php',
   type: 'POST',
   processData:false,
   dataType: "json",
   data: "json=" + JSON.stringify(all_data),
   success: function(res){
   var json_a = $.parseJSON(res);
   console.log(json_a);
   },
   error: function(err){
   console.log("error");
   }
});
```

**JSON that is created**

```
[json] => [{"name":"jhb","text":"gjh","point":"jhv","phase":"planning","date":"21/9/2013 - 4:23:16","author":"Created by - ljhlkjhb"}]
```

**PHP**

```
print_r($_POST); // prints out entire JSON
print($_POST["json"][0]["story_name"]);
// Warning : Illegal string offset 'story_name' in C:\xampp\htdocs\save_server_script.php on line 15
print($_POST["json"][0]); // prints out a '['
foreach($_POST["json"] as $hello) { // invalid argument supplied for foreach
    print $hello["story_name"];
}
```

I have also tried decoding via PHP but to no avail.

Comment: Where is your question ?

Comment: Apologies. I need the JSON to be manipulated like an array in PHP, for example, $_POST["json"][0]["story_name"] or something like that, as I will need to loop through the JSON if there is more data.

Comment: _"it behaves like a string"_ - That's because JSON is, by definition, a string. To use it in your PHP you need to do what Mike W said in his answer. Note, however, that if your PHP returns JSON in its response you do _not_ need to use `$.parseJSON()` in your ajax success handler because when you specify `dataType:"json"` jQuery will parse it for you automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$json = json_decode($_POST['json']);

echo $json[0]->author;
```

In your snippet you're referring to `story_name`, but that's not an element in your JSON string.

Comment: Its been a long day, my local copy has everything working fine, must have messed up on stack. Apologies, this solution does not work.

Comment: @TheSunny Not sure what 'does not work' means. See this [fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/51e-b9p)

Answer (score 0):

You have to decode the json into array in php first:

```
$arr = json_decode($_POST["json"]);
 //now you can use foreach on the array it returned
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
   //now you can use $value["text"] , $value["author"] etc
}
```

The data received by php is in json format that needed to be converted into array format in order to use foreach on it.
PS There is not "story_name" in your json data.

Comment: I tried your solution and this error is thrown:
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\save_server_script.php on line 19. Which is where I have tried to print the 'print $value["text"];'

Comment: This seems to print out the entire JSON string.
    `foreach($arr as $value){
 foreach ($value as $hi) {
  print $hi;
 }
     }`

Comment: It will print out all the values in json string, not the json string itself, because you iterated through each value and printed them all. If it is actually printing the string in json format then there must be a mistake.